# Data structure design for supporting arbitrary number of columns in table or database

Tags: dataset, data, databases

I'm currently working on a sort-of a meta-modeler to build a free web service so that people can input data and run several models on that data.

The task I'm currently struggling is: user needs to enter data column by column, which would consist of a number n of ID's , a number m of attributes and a number k of classes, with the conditions that n, m > 0 and k >= 0. Data is heterogeneous, so indexes can be both numeric or text, and the same goes for attributes and classes. I'm supposing there will be no null in the data for simplicity.

I'm currently thinking on:

1) Creating a table with more than enough columns (all with null values), so that I can work using only the non-null columns (which will be got from user input). However this would limit the size of the datasets people could input.

2) Resorting to create an specialized data structure on a programming language, do all the work there and finally, create a table dynamically  to store the result data there.

3) Using a database specialized for this kind of data (maybe a document-based DB).

4) Create a data structure on the RDBMS itself (I'm using PostgreSQL), let's say a variable size array, so that I can create the table directly from the user input, using only 3 variable arrays (one for indexes, one for attributes and one for classes). However, I keep in mind that attributes and indexes could be of different types, so the array would have to support heterogeneous data type and I don't know if this is possible on a RDBMS or SQL.

I've been looking for information on information but got no result until now. Any guidances to a package, language library, extension or paper, thesis, technical report with relevant information would be appreciated.
Also, personal experiences with doing something similar could be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something like you're describing using [mongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/)--I think you'll best use your time using some sort of NoSQL approach, rather than creating a specialized one-off solution. If you're using Python, I've had excellent experiences using [PyMongo](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/) to handle reads and writes from within my code.

I would strongly caution you against adopting your approach #1. This could break very easily in the future, and there are databases designed to handle your exact problem!

Comment: So you recommend the approach of modeling the schema using a document and then inserting the columns (whose number if variable) as subdocuments?

Comment: Not necessarily. In this case I was thinking more specifically in a mongoDB world view, wherein you can use any javascript data type. So, in this case, you could have a document with a field that is a list or list of lists, of varying length. Does that make sense?

Comment: In the generic sense of the list yes. However I have no knowledge of Javascript. Do I need to use necessarily JS datatypes or is it possible to use dataypes from another language? (in concrete C++ or Haskell)

Comment: I don't think knowledge of javascript is required for mongo, though it does help if you use the mongo shell. Here's a list of supported types from their docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/

Comment: You don't necessarily have to use mongoDB, if that's not your preference, though I do strongly recommend some sort of NoSQL approach for what you're doing!

Comment: Yes, I am almost sure to choose NoSQL approach. Can you recommend another mature NoSQL database solutions? (I would prefer open-source ones).

Comment: We've used Apache Cassandra here for my work, but it might be overkill for what you're doing. This table might be helpful in making an informed choice based on your requirements: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Performance

Comment: I see. Let me ask you something. Is it possible to create the table in advance so that the size of the datatype or container extends itself to fit all the data entered by the user? Or do I need to create the table through a script just after the dataset is submitted?

Comment: I'm not sure about that...I imagine you can find information on that somewhere on stackoverflow!  My gut feeling is that you shouldn't need to pre-create a table at all. I'd image space is dynamically allocated, but I'm more of a data science person, rather than a DBadmin :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a combination of 2) and 3) in your scenario above.

For 2) use JSON as it allows you to construct an arbitrary structure on the fly with as many columns as you need without tying yourself to a fixed schema. JSON also has wide language adoption (Python, R, Java, Scala eg).

For 3) I agree that MongoDB is the simplest as it is designed to be used for JSON.